# Make chrome's ctrl + enter shortcut only append the .com

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

When you type a website into the omnibox of chrome and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it appends a `www.` and a `.com` to the URL. For example, typing superuser, then hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> would bring me to www.superuser.com

However, this doesn't work with a subdomain. For example, typing meta.superuser would bring me to www.meta.superuser.com, which is not a valid domain.

Is there a way to prevent chrome from adding the www. (in all cases, not just if there's a subdomain) and only add the .com?

Comment: <g> That's about as good as my suggesting "by using Firefox" which easily lets you control this.  Have you tried: chrome://flags and set "Inline HistoryQuickProvider suggestions" to "Prohibited"?

Comment: @Debra I like the HistoryQuickProvider, it's very useful. That's not what I'm trying to disable.

Answer (score 0):

u cannot change ctrl+enter behaviour in chrome. try firefox or vivaldi :)